# How to get ec2 instance state programmatically using dotnet core

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, aws-sdk

I have following

1. Instance ID, Access key, Secret key.
2. AWS SDK has been set up correctly.

I need a **dotnet code snippet** to get the instance state (pending, running, shutting-down, terminated, stopping or stopped)

```
var instanceId = "i-0exxxxxxxx"; 
var request = new DescribeInstancesRequest { InstanceIds = new List<string>{instanceId }};
var response = await _amazonEc2.DescribeInstancesAsync(request);
... 
var state = ???
```

Above response doesn't contain the instance state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describe EC2 instance method returns reservation which then has information about instances.

DescribeInstancesAsync returns DescribeInstancesResponse.

- Which then has DescribeInstancesResult -->
- Amazon.EC2.Model.Reservation  -->
- Amazon.EC2.Model.Instance -->
- State -->  Name

Comment: I didn't knew that. The state was there on `response.reservations[0].instances[0].state`